# Do tags also stand in for sequels?

Tags: discussion, tags

If there is a tag for a game (generally this applies to less popular/proeminent games), can I use that tag for the game's sequel (this applies at least to the tag "sanctum", because sanctum 2 does not have a tag itself)? I know that most games already have a tag, even if they are sequels to games with existing tags (elder scrolls, gta, etc), but I can imagine that we don't have a tag for each and every game out there. Is there supposed to be tags for each and every sequel, or do we just keep using the old one if there won't be too much appearing on the tag anyways?

Comment: Is it that sanctum 2 doesn't have a tag or that there are no sanctum 2 questions?

Comment: Probably the latter, I didn't check. Will in a bit, will edit this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, sequels get their own tag - if you can't make the tag on your own, ask for it in comments or as you did here. After all, a sequel is usually its own whole game and questions about one don't always apply in full to the other.

If the sequel isn't actually a separate game but is more of an expansion, then it may warrant sharing a tag, but I can't think of any example that we would do this for.

Comment: Most of the Mass Effect DLCs share their parent game tag

Comment: Are those sequels or expansions? We have, for example, Diablo II and Lord of Destruction which share the same tag, but not Diablo and Diablo II.

Comment: Well we've had discussions about whether DLCs are expansions or not in the past I think, they're not sequels though, all of the sequels have separate tags. If I had to chose out of the two options they'd be expansions.

Comment: Prior art for an expansion sharing a tag: we use [[tag:doom]] for both Doom and [Ultimate Doom](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ultimate+doom%22). Which is appropriate since there is only an extra bit of content, and since the community and [other sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_versions_of_Doom#MS-DOS) treat them as effectively the same game, unlike more significant rewrites like Final Doom. I believe we do (or would do; I can't find any questions for the latter) this for Half-Life and Half-Life: Source as well.